# Is there a way to use multiple fonts with jsPDF doc.html

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, custom-font

I'm trying to use something like `<div style="font-family: Helvetica, myFont;">` where myFont is an added custom font. But when I convert it into pdf using `doc.html(document.getElementById('to-pdf'))`, only the Helvetica font is used.

It manages to load properly if I use only the custom font `<div style="font-family: myFont;">`, so my question is if there is a way to use `<div style="font-family: Helvetica, myFont;">` instead. This is because I'm mainly using the custom font to display the glyphs for other languages, and I want the English text to be displayed in Helvetica because it looks better.